# Alternatives to nested for loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop, nested

I need to take an element in array one, and compare it to every other element of array two to see if there's a match.  I need to do this for every element in array one.

```
for ( let i = 0, j = userArray.length; i < j; i++) {
            for ( let c = 0, d = userArray.length; c < d; c++) {
              object = {
                id: userArray[i].account,
                name: userArray[i].name,
                title: "",
                rating: ""
              }

              if ( userArray[i].account === accountArray[c].id) {

                object.title = accountArray[c].title.title

              }

              if (object.title !== ""){
                objectArray.push(object)

              }

            }

          }
```

is there a more efficient approach to this.

the desired outcome is to compare every element of accountArray to each individual element of userArray to search for matches

Comment: It looks like you meant for one of the loops to iterate over the `accountArray` array. Probably the inner loop, given the usage.

Comment: it does actually iterate over the account array in the if statement, as im just using the counter in the index! :)

Comment: The inner loop will continue based on the length of `userArray`, which seems to be incorrect. If the arrays are not the same length you will either encounter an exception (`userArray` is longer than `accountArray`) or you will miss out on elements from the accountArray (`userArray` is shorter than `accountArray`).

Comment: both arrays are the same length but point duly noted and will amend, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array `reduce()` method to filter and map your `userArray` into a new array with combined results.

Here's an example (with stubbed data):

```js
const userArray = [
  { account: 1, name: 'user 1' },
  { account: 2, name: 'user 2' },
  { account: 3, name: 'user 3' },
  { account: 4, name: 'user 4' },
  { account: 5, name: 'user 5' }
];

const accountArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'account 1', title: 'account 1 title' },
  { id: 3, name: 'account 3', title: 'account 3 title' },
  { id: 5, name: 'account 5', title: 'account 5 title' }
];

const mergedList = userArray.reduce((acc, u) => {
  const account = accountArray.find(a => a.id === u.account);
  
  if (account) {
    acc.push({ 
      id: u.account,
      name: u.name,
      title: account.title,
      rating: ''
    })
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(mergedList);
```

You can read about the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method and the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

Comment: upvoted back to zero.  I would actually love to hear more.

Comment: Why not use map instead of reduce? In the end we are looping over an array and then doing another loop with `.find` on every element. 

Comment: @Ajay -- It's not apparent to me how one would do this with `map()`. Post your suggestion as an answer and I'll take a look.

Answer (score -2):

You can either use Array.find or Array.filter

**Array.find** - returns the first matching element

`array.find(item => item.id === 1)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

**Array.filter** - returns an array of all the matching elements

`array.filter(item => item.id === 1)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Hope it helps!